# Why results from R's wilcox_test and Matlab's ranksum are not consistent?

Tags: nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I found when using two sample ranksum test, Matlab's ranksum gives different p value from R's wilcox_test (seems to be related to unequal sample size), I'm not capable of delving into their implementations. Anyone has a clue? Thanks.

Matlab side:

```
ranksum(ones(1,5), [1,2,2,2],'method', 'exact')
```

results: p =  0.0952

R side:

```
library(coin)
var <- c(rep('a', 5), rep('b', 4))
val <- c(rep(1, 5), c(1,2,2,2))
d <- data.frame(var, val)
wilcox_test(val~var, data=d, distribution='exact')
```

results: p = 0.04762

What's also confusing to me, when the p values are not the same, R's p is usually half of that from Matlab. Whey 'a' and 'b' have equal sample size,  R and Matlab produce the same results.

Comment: You should take the mathematical fact that $2\times 0.04762=0.0952$ as a very strong clue, and then consult the relevant help pages.

Comment: Both ranksum in Matlab and wilcox_test in R are saying they are two-sided tests. And if sample `a` and `b` have same length, the results not different. So I doubt it's a simple sideness issue.

Comment: If that's what the documentation says, then it's likely a bug in one of them (or a lapse in documentation).  One thing that might be worth trying is to test two cases involving the same large amounts of data, differing only in that in one case the two samples are the same size and in the other case their sizes differ by one. The p-values should be almost the same in both cases and for both software platforms.  That could help you isolate the problematic behavior.

Comment: It's possibly a difference in handling ties (note that `wilcox_test` offers several different options for dealing with ties). Where you say "usually", can you show a case that is neither equal nor half as big? What happens when $n_1\neq n_2$ but there are no ties?

Comment: @whuber This is nice way to pinpoint the problem, Unfortunately the 'exact' method can only be used when sample size is small, and I'm only interested in applying the 'exact' method, therefore I can't test with large amount of data.

Comment: @Glen_b `ranksum(1:6, 6:10,'method', 'exact')` in Matlab gives `p = 0.0087`, and wilcox_test gives `p = 0.006494`. When there is no ties, like `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` and `b = [7, 8, 9, 10]`, both R and Matlab produce `p = 0.0095`. So it may be difference in tie treatment.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still thinking it might be ties. Note that your samples in the post are small enough to list all the permutations by hand.

Comment: @acat For the additional examples you cite, you can also adapt my code from the answer I have just posted. For the first case with `y <- c(1:6, 6:10)` and `perm <- combn(11, 6)` and for the second case with `y <- 1:10` and `perm <- combn(10, 6)`.  In the latter case the distribution of the test statistic becomes symmetric (see `barplot(prop.table(table(rs)))`) so that the p-values from all strategies 1-3 coincide.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that this is a difference in how the two-sided p-value is computed. In exact tests with non-symmetric distributions (as in your unbalanced example), there are different conceivable ways to accomplish this. See for example the discussion of the two-sided [Binomial test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_test#Example_binomial_test) and [Sign test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_test#Significance_testing) on Wikipedia:

1. One strategy is compute the left-sided $\mbox{Pr}(S \le s)$ and the right-sided $\mbox{Pr}(S \ge s)$ and then take twice the minimum out of these. My guess is that this is what MATLAB uses.
2. A different approach is to add to the smaller of these p-values the probability of observing an at least as extreme statistic on the other tail. If the test statistic S is standardized (as in the R/coin package) then one can do this via $\mbox{Pr}(S \le -|s|) + \mbox{Pr}(S \ge |s|)$.
3. Finally, one can some over all possible $\mbox{Pr}(S = s_i)$ that are at least as unlikely as the $\mbox{Pr}(S = s)$ for the observed statistic $s$.

In your example, we can easily carry out all approaches explicity in R. First, we generate the data, all 126 permutations, and the rank sums (using average ranks).

```
y <- rep(1:2, c(6, 3))
perm <- combn(9, 5)
rs <- apply(perm, 2, function(i) sum(rank(y)[i]))
```

To be able to apply strategy 2, we scale the rank sums (which makes no difference at all for strategies 1 and 3):

```
rss <- (rs - mean(rs)) / sqrt(mean((rs - mean(rs))^2))
rss[1]
## [1] -2.236068
```

which replicates the test statistic reported by R/coin. The exact distribution is given by:

```
prop.table(table(rs))
## rs
##       17.5         22       26.5         31 
## 0.04761905 0.35714286 0.47619048 0.11904762 
prop.table(table(rss))
## rss
##  -2.23606797749979 -0.894427190999916  0.447213595499958   1.78885438199983 
##         0.04761905         0.35714286         0.47619048         0.11904762
```

Then, the first strategy gives this p-value (as reported by MATLAB):

```
2 * min(c(mean(rss <= rss[1]), mean(rss >= rss[1])))
## [1] 0.0952381
```

The second strategy gives the following p-value (as reported by R/coin):

```
mean(rss <= -abs(rss[1])) + mean(rss >= abs(rss[1]))
## [1] 0.04761905
```

And the third strategy gives

```
p <- prop.table(table(rss))
sum(p[p <= mean(rss == rss[1])])
## [1] 0.04761905
```

While strategy 1 is discussed in the literature - specifically for sign tests and rank tests (see the Wikipedia "Sign test" link above) - something like 2 or 3 is typically preferred (as argued in the Wikipedia "Binomial test" link above).

Comment: Matlab's ranksum has `p_tail = min(plo,phi); p = min(2*p_tail, 1);` This is the cause. Thanks a lot for the comments!